# Web Logic Deployment

Tags: weblogic

13:55:11 Deployment Message : weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid schema document passed to AbstractDataBinding.addSchemaDocument, not in W3C schema namespace

How to handle the above exepction.

Comment: going to need more information.  Where did you see this message, what were you doing, etc

Comment: While deploying my war file to Weblogic server I am getting this namespace error.